# I need to redirect based on the response to an html Form submission

Tags: javascript, html

for example

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
    <p> Do you like cats or dogs </p>
    <input type="radio" id="cat" value="Cats">
    <label for="cat">Cats</label>
    <input type="radio" id="dog" value="Dogs">
    <label for="dog">Dogs</label><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitForm(event) {
        if(document.getElementById('cat').checked) {
            //(send the user to the cat page)
  
        }else if(document.getElementById('dog').checked) {
            //(send the user to the dog page)
        }
</script>
```

how would I send users to different pages in the same root folder as my website based on their responses to my questions

Answer (score 3):

Give `window.location.href` a shot

```
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
    <p> Do you like cats or dogs </p>
    <input type="radio" id="cat" value="Cats">
    <label for="cat">Cats</label>
    <input type="radio" id="dog" value="Dogs">
    <label for="dog">Dogs</label><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitForm(event) {
        if(document.getElementById('cat').checked) {
            //(send the user to the cat page)
            window.location.href = 'yoursite.com/cat'
  
        }else if(document.getElementById('dog').checked) {
            //(send the user to the dog page)
            window.location.href = 'yoursite.com/dog'
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Formatting

First, there are a few errors in the code that need to be fixed.

The radio inputs are missing the `name` attribute. Without a value for the `name` attribute set, it is an orphan.

Each of the radio inputs below can be checked at the same time and would result in unexpected behavior.

In addition, there is a missing curly brace at the end of the JavaScript function 'submitForm'

```html
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <p> Do you like cats or dogs </p>

  <!-- Missing 'name' attribute' -->
  <input type="radio" id="cat" value="Cats">
  <label for="cat">Cats</label>

  <!-- Missing 'name' attribute' -->
  <input type="radio" id="dog" value="Dogs">
  <label for="dog">Dogs</label><br>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function submitForm(event) {
    if (document.getElementById('cat').checked) {
      //(send the user to the cat page)

    } else if (document.getElementById('dog').checked) {
      //(send the user to the dog page)
    }
  // <-Missing closing curly brace for 'submitForm'
</script>
```

To fix these issues, here is the HTML you posted with the missing pieces filled in.
*Note that only one of the choices can be selected now.*

```html
<form onsubmit="submitForm(event)">
  <p>Do you like cats or dogs</p>
  
  <!-- Now has a name attribute set to 'PetChoiceRadioGroup' -->
  <input type="radio" id="cat" value="Cats" name="PetChoiceRadioGroup" />
  <label for="cat">Cats</label>
  
  <!-- Now has a name attribute set to 'PetChoiceRadioGroup' -->
  <input type="radio" id="dog" value="Dogs" name="PetChoiceRadioGroup" />
  <label for="dog">Dogs</label><br>
  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


<script>
  function submitForm(event) {
    if (document.getElementById('cat').checked) {
      //(send the user to the cat page)

    } else if (document.getElementById('dog').checked) {
      //(send the user to the dog page)
    }
  } // <-Curly brace no longer missing
</script>
```

After fixing these issues, [kawnah’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5481714/kawnah) answer is a good solution using location.href to change pages based on the choice selected.